Cannot resolve symbol "appcompat" and the whole project is buggy. (Android Studio)
Everything is red and buggy. I don't know what heppened there. I think there are some problems with Android Studio IDE. The XML still work normal but the Java code doesn't.
Here is my code
I recently change the DNS setting from my PC to Google public DNS, I think it might be the problem but it's unlikely.
I just created a new app to test and haven't make any changes to the code. That code is from my 3rd attempt to create a new test project. I tried to add the dependency on androidx.appcompat:appcompat and import because it recomend it to me. However, after the gradle sync, nothing happends and the bugs is still there. I tried to reinstall Android  Studio several times but it doesn't work either.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
